# Windows 10: restore system image backup to a different hdd?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-backup

So I made a system image to a USB hdd using these instructions:

https://www.cnet.com/au/how-to/how-to-create-a-system-image-in-windows-10/

I'm wondering if it's possible to restore to a different hdd in case I decided to replace the old hdd?

Thanks

Comment: Did you make a repair disc or have the install disc? Because you should be able to do this if you have one of those items. Should be able to select repair using an image. I can double check when i get home for you. On a windows Tablet at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

We could  create an Image Backup then restore the backup to your new hard drive, if you want to replace the hard drive.

Here is a link for reference of the detailed steps:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbVT4XQcB1A

Comment: Please provide all relevant details in the body of your answer.  Link-only answers, specially to YouTube, do not make adequate answers